# EViews Output and Tables

Tags: tables

EViews has an add-in which apparently outputs latex, but I can't install it on my faculty computers. I can save the output as a csv. Is there any way of me creating nicer looking tables in my document without having to input the numbers in manually?

Comment: You might have a look at the datatool (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool) and csvsimple (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple) packages, especially (given your needs) the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take [`pgfplotstable`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) to typeset csvdata as a table. It is a highly configurable package. I cannot compare it to [`datatool`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool) or [`csvsimple`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple) (see comment of @Paul Stanley) though, because I haven't used one of them. The following code shows a simple example with three different column types. For more options see the comprehensive [manual of pgfplotstable](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Month, Small Value, Large Value
January, 12.50, 12.3E5
February, 3.32, 8.7E3
March, 43, 3.1E6
April, 0.33, 21.2E4
May, 5.12, 3.45E6
June, 6.44, 6.66E6
July, 123.2, 7.3E7
August, 12.3, 5.3E4
September, 2.3, 4.4E4
October, 6.5, 6.5E6
November,0.55, 5.5E5
December,2.2, 3.3E3
\end{filecontents}

% Define style for cvs file format
\pgfplotstableset{
    csv file/.style={col sep=comma,row sep=newline}
}

% Add rules for all 'pgfplotstable's
\pgfplotstableset{
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule}
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[csv file,
        column type=l, % default is left alignment
        columns/Month/.style={string type},
        columns/Small Value/.style={dec sep align}, % align at the decimal point
        columns/Large Value/.style={sci,sci sep align} % use scientific notation                                         
        ]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSV example using the `csvsimple` package for reading the data and the `siunitx` package for formatting the numbers. I'm taking the example data from @quinmars who showed `pgfplotstable`. `datatool` would be the third candidate.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Month, Small Value,  Large Value
January, 12.50, 12.3E5
February, 3.32, 8.7E3
March, 43, 3.1E6
April, 0.33, 21.2E4
May, 5.12, 3.45E6
June, 6.44, 6.66E6
July, 123.2, 7.3E7
August, 12.3, 5.3E4
September, 2.3, 4.4E4
October, 6.5, 6.5E6
November,0.55, 5.5E5
December,2.2, 3.3E3
\end{filecontents*}

\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}

\csvloop{%--- from csvsimple
  file=data.csv,
  tabular={lSS[table-figures-exponent=1]},%--- column 'S' from siunitx
  table head=\toprule\textbf{Month} & \textbf{Small Value} & \textbf{Large Value}\\\midrule,
  command=\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii\relax,
  table foot=\bottomrule}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I usually use [Excel2LaTeX](https://launchpad.net/excel2latex), on OSx I use [csv2LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csv2latex). The latter integrates really nicely to `TeXShop` via a Perl plugin that allows on-the-fly copy pasting of table code to latex code. The former integrates into `MS Excel` via VBA. It thus doesn't work properly on Mac but it's at least in my opinion one of the nicest ways of getting tables into LaTeX without much ado. If your output is in `csv`, you would have to import the file first or use text to columns in excel. Then you use the newly added ribbon to get the latex output.

Anyhow, when I looked into this a while back, these were the two most convenient solutions I found.